# How do I get getorgchart children into multiple columns

Tags: getorgchart

How do I get children of the parent to be in two columns? They are all horizontal. We have too many people with one direct report. I've searched the demos and could not find anything.

Comment: did you found any solution? I am stuck on same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mixed hierarchy

Here is an example

```
var orgChart = new getOrgChart(peopleElement, {
                primaryFields: ["name", "title", "phone", "mail"],
                photoFields: ["image"],
                expandToLevel: 100,
                layout: getOrgChart.MIXED_HIERARCHY_RIGHT_LINKS
});
```

also a demo page: http://www.getorgchart.com/Demos/Mixed-Hierarchy

Comment: What would be the reason for this not to work? I have about 85 people on the chart and for example 15 people report to one person, so they all have the same parentID and they are all beside each other and not like this example. User the CSV method, would that mess it up?

Comment: Try to increase the maxDepth option

Comment: Example:         var orgChart = new getOrgChart(peopleElement, {
            maxDepth: 200});

Comment: Odd. setting maxDepth did nothing.